# HTTPService xmlList - How to access to value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, air

I use httpservice with e4x format.
I put the result on XMLList (dpListePatient) like that

```
dpListePatient = event.result.patientPHP;
```

You can see below the xml

```
  <patientsPHP>
  <patientPHP>
    <id>17994</id>
    <nom>ZORDAN</nom>
    <prenom>Julien</prenom>
    <dos1>1940</dos1>
  </patientPHP>
</patientsPHP>
```

I 'd like to binding thsi result with some label on my form.
I try a lot of solution but any was good.
For exemple, I' d to access on id property, to do that, I try dpListePatient[0].id but when I test value is blank.
So can you explain to me how to access node value. Indeed on forum, I found a lot of message about attribute but not about node.
Thanks for helping

Comment: `dpListePatient[0].id ` it should work fine.. just check the value of `dpListePatient` whether it contains given XMLList?  have you declared dpListePatient as XMLList?

Comment: I don't why it's don't work this night but today is good. Thanks

Comment: i think you used `event.result.patientPHP;` instead event.result.patientsPHP;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is dpListPatient a `List` type (`*Collection` or `*List`)? 
If so you need to bind using

```
dpListPatient.getItemAt(index);
```

Bindings on `Array` types are not detected by Flash.

Comment: Then you should be able to bind it using `dpListPatient.getItemAt(index);`